# PingFederate: Error Signature Required on SP Initiated Login

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, pingfederate, idp

The PingFederate server responds with error Signature Required on SP initiated SSO, though we are sending Signature Value in the SAML auth request. Following is the request I am sending to Ping Federate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" > > xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" > AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://mycompany.com/saml2/acs/" Destination="https://idp.com/idp/SSO.saml2" ID="id-1305fe524135c3980b2446c10dec5f08" IssueInstant="2017-11-21T18:27:17Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" ProviderName="My Service" Version="2.0">
  <saml:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">https://mycompany.com/</saml:Issuer>
  <ds:Signature Id="Signature1">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
      <ds:Reference URI="#id-1305fe524135c3980b2446c10dec5f08">
        <ds:Transforms>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <ds:DigestValue>PgekvX9t5tSi2t……..KMSXBPFMlhjcpk=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>m0/……………….J5bmNQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
      <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Certificate>MII………………o6jkYDUjhprKdQ+m4=</ds:X509Certificate>
      </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
  </ds:Signature>
  <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified"/>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

I have shortened Signature Value and Certificate for better readability.
PingFederate is rejecting this request with SAML response

```
<samlp:Status xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester" />
<samlp:StatusMessage>Signature required</samlp:StatusMessage></samlp:Status>
```

Following are logs of PingFederate:

```
2017-11-21 13:27:17,222 tid:pSs3mUSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSXLK4 DEBUG [org.sourceid.websso.servlet.ProtocolControllerServlet] [qtp2106609649-286] ---REQUEST (GET)/idp/SSO.saml2 from 123.123.123.3:
---PARAMETERS---
SAMLRequest:
3VZJl6LYEt7nr/BYi1p4U……<shortened request for readability>…….zdsjP10u10KWIGwjw6it3/9v4/+l78B
RelayState:
/myAppDashboard/index.html?sso_user=user1%40myidp.com&tenant_domain=xyz.com#/
2017-11-21 13:27:17,222 tid:pSs3mUSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSXLK4 DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.bindings.BindingFactory] [qtp2106609649-286] GET
with Params: [SAMLRequest, RelayState]
assume binding: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect
from: 123.123.123.3
Referer: https://mycompany.com/saml2/login/?email=user1%40myidp.com&tenantIdentifier=undefined(https://mycompany.com/saml2/login/?email=user1%40myidp.com&tenantIdentifier=undefined)
AuthType: null
Content-Type: null
2017-11-21 13:27:17,225 tid:pSs3mUSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSXLK4 DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.bindings.LoggingInterceptor] [qtp2106609649-286] Received InMessageContext:
InMessageContext
XML: https://mycompany.com/saml2/acs/" Destination="https://idp.com/idp/SSO.saml2" ID="id-1305fe524135c3980b2446c10dec5f08" IssueInstant="2017-11-21T18:27:17Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" ProviderName="My Service" Version="2.0" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig# (http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig) " xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
https://mycompany.com/ (https://mycompany.com/%3c/saml:Issuer) >
http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
PgekvX9t5tSi2t/………………J5bmNQ==
MIIDpjCC……………………Q+m4=
entityId: https://mycompany.com/ (https://mycompany.com/) (SP)
virtualServerId: XYZSSO2.0
Binding: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect
relayState: /myAppDashboard/index.html?sso_user=user1%40myidp.com&tenant_domain=xyz.com#/
SignatureStatus: NOT_PRESENT
Binding says to sign: true
2017-11-21 13:27:17,226 tid:pSs3mUSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSXLK4 DEBUG [org.sourceid.util.log.internal.TrackingIdSupport] [qtp2106609649-286] [cross-reference-message] entityid:null subject:null
2017-11-21 13:27:17,226 tid:pSs3mUSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSXLK4 ERROR [org.sourceid.saml20.profiles.idp.HandleAuthnRequest] [qtp2106609649-286] Exception occurred during request processing
org.sourceid.saml20.profiles.StatusResponseException: Signature required
……..
…….
2017-11-21 13:27:17,251 tid:pSs3mUSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSXLK4 DEBUG [org.sourceid.servlet.HttpServletRespProxy] [qtp2106609649-286] flush cookies: adding Cookie{PF=hashedValue:pSs3mUSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSXLK4; path=/; maxAge=-1; domain=null}
2017-11-21 13:27:17,252 tid:pSs3mUSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSXLK4 DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.bindings.LoggingInterceptor] [qtp2106609649-286] Transported Response. OutMessageContext:
OutMessageContext
XML: https://mycompany.com/saml2/acs/" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
XYZSSO2.0
http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
vRc7z0pcj5wzfn/………….UV3nYqUjgsnwHx9tziUqFwmAI=
Signature required
entityId: https://mycompany.com/ (https://mycompany.com/) (SP)
virtualServerId: XYZSSO2.0
Binding: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
relayState: /myAppDashboard/index.html?sso_user=user1%40myidp.com&tenant_domain=xyz.com#/
Endpoint: https://mycompany.com/saml2/acs/ (https://mycompany.com/saml2/acs/)
SignaturePolicy: BINDING_DEFAULT
2017-11-21 13:27:18,348 DEBUG [org.sourceid.servlet.HttpServletRespProxy] [qtp2106609649-101] adding lazy cookie Cookie{PF=hashedValue:E0oc11111111111111VkfIwa0I; path=/; maxAge=-1; domain=null} replacing null
2017-11-21 13:27:18,348 tid:E0oc11111111111111VkfIwa0I DEBUG [org.sourceid.websso.servlet.IntegrationControllerServlet] [qtp2106609649-101] GET: https://idp.com/idp/startSSO.ping
```

Need help how can we fix this problem, any knob/flag which could be set on Ping Federate to make it work.

Comment: Not really a solution to this, but you can tell Ping to just not expect a signature, and then in the client don't pass it.

Comment: I am also facing same issue here. Did you find any solution. Pls share the same.

Answer (score 2):

It appears PingFed is expecting your message via Redirect Binding (you are making a GET request) but you are including the Signature in the Request like a Post binding.

Answer (score 0):

PingFederate expects SigAlg and signature as URL parameters along with SAMLRequest in the redirect URL. You need to correct the way you generate the SAML authentication request.

The URL should look like this:

{IDP target URL}?SAMLRequest={url_encoded_SAML_auth_req}&Signature={signature}&RelayState={optional_landing_url}&SigAlg={signature_algorithm}

I am using PySaml2 library and in my case, I had to use the below call to get a working SAML Signed Authn request.

saml_client.prepare_for_authenticate(relay_state=landing_url, sign=True, sigalg=sig_dict[args.sigalg])

You should be able to find the similar flag (sign, sigalg) for your library too.